# How can I add to the list of font substitutions in pdfbox 2.0.7?

Tags: fonts, pdfbox

I'm using `FontMapper.getTrueTypeFont()` to find available fonts by name in pdfbox 2.0.7.  This has a feature to map fonts (by name) so that if I ask for `Symbol` and my system only has `SymbolMT` it will return that as a substitute.

But the default implementation doesn't map the other way.  My system has `Symbol` installed, but if I try to get `SymbolMT` it returns `Helvetica` as the best match (which doesn't work very well).

The underlying `FontMapperImpl` class has an `addSubstitute()` method that lets you add mappings, but the class is private to the package so I can't call that (even though the method is marked public).  The `FontMapper` interface that `FontMapperImpl` implements does not include the `addSubstitute()` method.

In the [Cookbook for pdfbox 1.8](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html) there is a reference to using `Resources/PDFBox_External_Fonts.properties` to add mappings, but this does not seem to be present in pdfbox 2.0.7.

Is there a way to add additional font mappings (by name) in pdfbox 2.0.7, or do I need to build my own mapping layer outside of it?  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask for "symbol"? That's the name of that standard 14 font per pdf specification.

Comment: I want to add text to a PDF using a close approximation to the font that the file is already using.  So I'm getting the font name from an existing embedded font and then wanting to load the best local font that matches that one.  One of the PDF's I'm processing is using "SymbolMT".

So my goal is to have an automated process for doing that font matching.

Comment: It seemed like `FontMapper` is built to do things like this, but perhaps not.  Maybe it is only for finding fonts for displaying text in existing PDFs rather than for finding fonts for authoring new text.  The requirements might be different?  For example, I need to find only TTF fonts (not OTF ones) since my understanding is that I can't author new text with OTFs in PDFBox 2.*

Comment: I see... the substitute part is designed for the standard 14 only, which get special treatment. (There's some magic for other fonts too) From what I see, SymbolMT in a PDF file wouldn't be considered a standard 14 font so PDFBox would simply look whether it exists and it not, then the described effect from your 2nd paragraph happens. So on your system rendering would fail. I think you should rather copy and modify FontMapperImpl for your needs, and then assign that one by calling `FontMappers.set(new MatthewHisFontMapperImpl())`.

Comment: Yes you're the first one who wants to use that for creating. It's designed for rendering / extracting PDF files. But as I said, feel free to be inspired by the code to choose the best font. Yes we support only ttf and ttf collections. FileSystemFontProvider.java and related may also be useful to you.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestions.