# Different rendering of bulletpoints on different platforms

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF which is rendered to an image but the result is different on different platforms.

[image] [image]

Now I investigated and found that the "Symbol" font used is available on windows but not on linux. Also it is not embedded. So far so good. Reason found. Now before [PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) I used [jpedal](https://github.com/Lonzak/JPedal) for rendering and with jpedal however the PDF is rendered correctly on linux. So now my question is how can that be? Is there the possibility to use a better replacement font? Or is there an invalid glyph mapping which is handled better in jpedal?

The PDF is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12zc900OJvuB9_WN6dspzJz6bWRR45Mht). I am using PdfBox 2.0.19.

On linux I get the following warnings (but not on windows):

```
[WARN ] 2020-06-11 22:28:28,148 org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.<init>() - Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'SymbolMT'
[WARN ] 2020-06-11 22:28:28,199 org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.<init>() - Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'ArialMT'
```

For Arial it seems to be a good replacement but not for SymbolMT. Symbol (part of the base14 fonts) would be a much better choice... I also found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320624/how-can-i-add-to-the-list-of-font-substitutions-in-pdfbox-2-0-7)...

Comment: Any log message?

Comment: See my update on the linux warnigs

Comment: Is this symbol font on your system? It should be accepted, source code has the line "substitutes.put("Symbol", Arrays.asList("Symbol", "SymbolMT", "StandardSymL"));".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr No the symbol font is not installed - thats the problem. There is only the DejaVu Font family installed (as its the case on many linux systems). "SymbolMT" is the fontname used in the PDF. But I saw that you ship the base14 fonts along with PDFBox (...resources\afm\Symbol.afm). Why isn't this font taken as a replacement?

Comment: The afm files only contain the metrics (in particular widths) of the glyphs, not their actual appearance.

Comment: We are not shipping the std14 fonts. We have only one single font that is a desperate fallback.

Comment: But how do you then render PDFs without embedded fonts at all? Always and for everything use the LiberationSans font? I thought the base14 must always be there...And now I am puzzled how jpedal managed to render bullet points without the font. They don't even distribute a fallback font.

Comment: We use whatever is on the system and seems to be similar. Maybe jpedal uses fonts from Java itself?

Comment: Have a look at PdfJavaGlyphs.java and PdfFont.java. I think this confirms my theory but I haven't traced through it. (And I won't).

Comment: But Java itself isn't supplying any fonts. It just defines five logical font names: serif, sansserif, monospaced, dialog, and dialoginput which are then mapped to the fonts on the operating system (fontconfig in the java_home folder). Which is in a pristine linux installation the DejaVu Font family. So basically this is the difference: PdfBox is using its own fallback font (liberationSans) and jpedal is using the system fallback font (DejaVu) font. Interestingly in this case the system fonts seems to be the better choice. Is there any possibility to influence Pdfbox to use the system font?

Comment: No this is hard coded.

Comment: I can't find this on Amazon Corretto 11. Maybe this is different in Linux than in Windows.

Comment: That would be quite strange. If you look at your corretto folder jdk....\jre\lib\fontconfig.properties.src There must be such a file. If not your corretto installation is broken. (Or they did change the location so just search your corretto installation for "fontconfig.properties").

Comment: On jdk11 it is in C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.7_10\lib . I don't see how this would help here. Does DejaVu contain the "Symbol" glyphs?

Comment: My knowledge of fonts is too limited in that area. https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/Samples.html But I don't know which character is used. There is at least the bullet point char in there...

Comment: Can you build from source? It would be interesting to hear what happens if you replace LiberationSans in FontMapperImpl.java with DejaVu Sans.

Comment: I did a test, and the font is not perfect, it fails to render (C), (R), TM and some of the bullet points. I suspect it has something to do with different encodings for symbols.

Comment: Great that you tried it out. But for that specific document were the bullet points correctly rendered? Would it be a possible solution to add a 2nd fallback font for symbols to pdfbox?

Comment: @Lonzak please "@" my name or I don't see responses. I tried and it works for that file. I've been thinking of having several fallbacks, but that is for mono / times. Your font is not a good replacement for symbol.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes I wouldn't probably use it as a replacement font for symbol. I just mentioned it since it is the only font installed on many linux systems. But the idea of having several fallback fonts sounds great! I would add 3 for mono/times and symbol :-)