# Load a barcode font for PDFBox + Zxing recognition

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox, barcode, zxing

I have a component that gets a pdf file as byte array, loads it using Pdfbox library and then recognizes a barcode using Zxing library. I need to load 2 barcode fonts from a particular directory before recognition, without it the barcode would not be recognized. I tried to do execute this code:

```
PDDocument document = ...;

PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, new File("...\fontFile.ttf"), Encoding.getInstance(COSName.STANDARD_ENCODING));

PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

document.getPage(0).getResources().add(font);
BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWIthDPI(0, dpi);
```

but it doesn't work, the font is not loaded to the right component (I don't know where it should be), the rendered image occurrs to be with a broken barcode and of course it fails during the following recognition.

Also I know that during the rendering java.awt.GraphicsEnvironmenttried is used. I tried to create it and add the font there, but it still doesn't work:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

env.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("...")));
BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWIthDPI(0, dpi);
```

Thanks in advance for ideas how to make this work. The font should be loaded from the project resources.

Comment: If you need the barcode fonts for rendering then you should put them into the official font directory of your computer. Also make sure you're using the latest version. No need to call `PDTrueTypeFont.load`. Make sure you're using the latest version (2.0.24).

Comment: Look also into your own user directory for the file `.pdfbox.cache`. You should find that barcode file there. If cache file isn't there, then you have an old PDFBox version. If the file is there but without a line for the font, then the font isn't found by PDFBox, i.e. you didn't put it into the font directory ( `C:/windows/fonts` if you're on windows)

Comment: Hi Tilman, Thank you. But I need to load barcode font from within the project directory, I can't check if every server has the needed file in the "Windows\fonts". And I use the latest lib version at that moment.

Comment: PDFBox doesn't support that. It's a bad practice to generate a PDF that assumes a font exists on the viewer machine. The font should be embedded in the PDF.

Comment: Maybe, but there is a lot of such documents - thousands or even hundreds of thousands. I can't update all the documents and embed the font in them.

Comment: I mean the software that creates them. Or are these archive documents? What you could do is to implement your own FontMapper and FontProvider by copying and modifying these parts of the source code. See `FontMappers.java` in the sources. See also my comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320624/